# What is the purpose of the performing a meta-refresh on the Worldpay Payment Response URL?

Tags: php, worldpay

After completing a transaction on a Worldpay hosted payment page, Worldpay sends a response to the Payment Response URL specified in the installation settings (eg example.com/thankyou.php).

The only way I've found to keep the user on the originating website is to use a meta-refresh on the Response URL page ([as per Worldpay docs](http://wp-support.crm.worldpay.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1049/~/how-do-i-redirect-the-shopper-to-the-redirection-location%3F)). Without the meta-refresh, the user remains on Worldpay's site and is shown their default thank you page.

What is the technical purpose of performing a meta-refresh? Is it to send a 200 header response back to Worldpay?

Comment: The purpose is to return to your webshop so the user isn't confused about why she's on worldpay's site instead of yours.

Comment: Thanks - I understand why I need to redirect, but not why it has to be done by a meta-refresh.

Comment: The meta refresh is a request you make to the client's browser, asking it to go to a specific URI. In this case, you use it to go back to the original website. No one sends a 200 "response" to the web server, the server is the one sending responses to requests.

Comment: Meta-refresh is just an example but it works without JavaScript enabled in the client's browser.